# jQuery cycle - previous button not working

Tags: jquery, css

Can someone see why my previous button is not working here?

```
$('#slideCycle').cycle({
     fx:     'fade', 
     timeout: 0, 
     next:   '#rightArrow', 
     prev:   '#leftArrow' 
});

<img src="/_images/left_arrow.jpg" id="leftArrow2">
<img src="/_images/right_arrow.jpg" id="rightArrow">
```

Also the cursor: pointer doesn't seem to be working on the left arrow.

Comment: why is it `leftArrow2`? remove the `2`

Comment: When I use firebug and hover over the elements, it seems the blocks are kind of messed up even though it displays nice. But if you add an z-index to the left arrow it will work however I think the issue is the way you set it up

Comment: @MarianTheisen There is an inconsistency between the code here and the page. The page is set up using the leftArrow2 while the code given here is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your image is covering it, try positioning it differently, or simply setting a higher z-index on the arrows.

Comment: Thanks, z-index fixed it.